# Bitnami-docker-keycloak on Heroku: Web process failed to bind to $PORT(Error R10)

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, port, keycloak

I want to put a docker image of keycloak on heroku and I followed the next instructions:

```
heroku auth:token
docker login --username=_ --password=${YOUR_TOKEN} registry.heroku.com
docker pull bitnami/keycloak:latest
docker images (to get image_id)
docker tag {image_id} registry.heroku.com/{heroku_app_name}/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/{heroku_app_name}/web
heroku container:release web -a {heroku_app_name}
```

After that I added [postgresql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ulO.png) on heroku followed by configuring [vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg3PG.png). Everything worked fine until I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSSzR.png). It doesn't work if I add another PORT vars in heroku

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hardcode the port (`8081`) on Heroku, but you must use the `$PORT` environment variable provided by you (this is the dynamic port for your Web Dyno).

> The web process must listen for HTTP traffic on $PORT

On Heroku you **cannot** run `docker run -e KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT=$PORT bitnami/keycloak:latest` but you can provide a Dockerfile to start the application with the configuration/variable you need (using `CMD`)

Comment: Where I should put the `$PORT` in their files? https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak/tree/master/13/debian-10 this is their git and I was looking for something like the next link to build my modified image: https://help.heroku.com/PPBPA231/how-do-i-use-the-port-environment-variable-in-container-based-apps